# Bluetooth mouse not detected

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

My Microsoft Bluetooth mouse worked fine on 17.10, but now, after the latest update, it is not detected anymore. Any ideas?

In *Settings -> Bluetooth* it does not appear anymore.
Before last night's update it has worked out of the box.

Comment: Did you try it with new batteries?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the obvious. But yes, I did.